# Passing array from one js file to another js file in a serverless framework

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, serverless

In One js file I'm assigning data to an object. That object has an array of objects.

```
const data = { 
  details: [
    {name: 'John', surname: 'Smith'},
    {name: 'Will', surname: 'Smith'},
    {name: 'Jessica', surname: 'Smith'}
  ]
};
```

I want to call this array in the below js file. This js file will return in html format. I want to call the data.details in html and get it in html table format. When I pass the array directly in the html it works. But its doesn't work when I'm passing it as $data.details.

```
const PDF = data => {
  return `<!doctype html>
          <html lang="en">
            <div>
              <p class="note">
                <b>Details:</b>
              </p>
              <table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-size: 14px; width: 500px;">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="col">
                      <h5>Name</h5>
                    </th>
                    <th scope="col">
                      <h5>Surname</h5>
                    </th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">         
                    var details = ${data.details};
                    for (var i = 0; i < details.length; i++) {
                      document.write("<tr><td>" + details[i].name + "</td>");
                      document.write("<td>" + details[i].surname + "</td>");                    
                    }
                  </script>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
          </body>
        </html>`;
};

export default { PDF };
```

Please help to to get this right. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't understand why you choose this way but you can load an external js file into a js file via jQuery.

```
$.getScript("script1.js", function() {
   console.log("script1 loaded. You can use script1 variables here!");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If the data is already available in the server-side, there is no need to render it client-side. Just construct your table right away.

```
const PDF = data => {
    const renderRow = detail => `
        <tr>
            <td>${detail.name}</td>
            <td>${detail.surname}</td>
        </tr>
    `

    const renderDetails = data => {
        return data.details.map(renderRow)
    }

    return `<!doctype html>
          <html lang="en">
            <div>
              <p class="note">
                <b>Details:</b>
              </p>
              <table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-size: 14px; width: 500px;">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="col">
                      <h5>Name</h5>
                    </th>
                    <th scope="col">
                      <h5>Surname</h5>
                    </th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  ${renderDetails(data)}
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
          </body>
        </html>`;
};

export default {PDF};
```